# parkingArea.occupancy in Veins

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am using sumo-0.30.0, and veins-4.7.1. I need to get parking occupancy from sumo.

How to add **parkingArea.occupancy** command in veins?

Please help me. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding traci command is not present in that old sumo version. So you would need to backport the traci command from a more recent sumo and then implement the veins counterpart. I doubt it is worth the effort and would strongly recommend to use a newer version of sumo and veins.